# User prompted for entering password again(even after being logged in Teams application) in Teams personal app if we use OAuth code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

We have created a Teams personal app which is **already** **published** in the Teams App Store. The authentication mechanism we follow is based on OAuth code flow, where we use authentication.authenticate() function provided by Teams js sdk to open login with Microsoft page. We specify all the required parameters like tenant id, client_id etc, along with **login_hint**. This opens up a new window with login.microsoft.com url and the user gets authenticated directly in Teams desktop and browser (Windows and Linux) i.e, the window which is opened up closes by it self and user doesn't need to enter his credentials again.

But in Mac devices and mobile devices, the window which is opened up doesn't close by itself and asks user to enter password again in spite of being logged-in inside Teams application.

How can we avoid user interaction to get the oauth code in Mac and mobile devices?

We do have methods to get AD token silently but getting AD token with a lot of scope in client side code and sending new token every time to backend when it expires is not a good idea we feel.
Is there any way we can get oauth code inside Teams personal app silently without user interaction?
Or is there any other way through which, we handle this scenario?

Comment: Would you please share your auth pages? You can try with samples [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/dev/hello-world-tab-with-backend/public).

Comment: @BowenSong Thank you for your response. We shouldn't be fetching access token in the front end :( We would need oauth2.0 code, and we send that to BE. Also, would you be comfortable, sharing your email id, so that we can share the code there. We shouldn't be sharing code in online platforms as per our company policies.

Comment: Can you say more about the overall scenario and what you're using the token or auth code for? There are ways to get a token silently (by calling authentication.getAuthToken in teamsjs). I'm not sure I understand the concern about getting the AD token in client side code or the concern about expiration.

Comment: Hey @AuthInfant please find the process we follow below:
1. User login into Teams application.
2. User find our personal app and opens it.
3. As the user has tenant id which is coming from getContext api of teams sdk, we open a window using authentication.authenticate of teams sdk and give the url as login.microsoftonline with respective tenant and client ids and other params.
4. Now as the user is already logged in inside teams, user will not be asked for re authentication, and microsoft redirects back to redirect uri with ?code=
5. As we get the code, we close the pop up.

Comment: 6. We send the code to BE, and with that auth code, BE fetches Microsoft token and sends us back our application based tokens.

Now, the problem is, when the small pop up opens up, in mobile and ios devices, microsoft again asks for re authentication, even though user is logged into Teams.
WE suppose this is because cookies not being shared in pop up windows in mobile and ios (both mobile ios and mac) devices.

So, for an alternative we found the SSO mechanism which teams personal app provides where we can acquire token silently. and also other mechanisms like msal.

Comment: But the problem is, we have to fetch that token in FE and send that to BE. We have few problem with that: as we need application specific tokens, we have to send back the Microsoft token timely to BE when ever the current token expires. And to acquire token in front end, we have to store some very sensitive information like client secret in front end which is against our security policies. Also, we have operations like calendar read write in our application, so it won't be secure it acquire it in front end.

Comment: How can we solve this issue. Is there any way we can get token in back end using the logged in person details? like FE will send the logged in person details( response from getContext api of teams sdk) and can BE generate a AD token with that?
Or do we have any api to get the auth code directly of the logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly based on the follow-up details (thanks for providing them!), the canonical way for Teams apps to handle this is to use the SSO flow enabled by teams-js in conjunction with the [on-behalf-of (OBO) flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow). You can read the full details about leveraging SSO at the [SSO overview page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview) and then see how to extend it to call other endpoints (like MS Graph) using the pattern described on the [extend tab app page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-graph-api?tabs=dotnet).

Overview of the flow:

1. Your Teams app calls [authentication.getAuthToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/authentication?view=msteams-client-js-latest#@microsoft-teams-js-authentication-getauthtoken). This function will return an authentication token, issued to Teams, for the resource you specify in the [webApplicationInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#webapplicationinfo) section of your app manifest. This resource should be your backend/middle-tier service.
2. Your Teams app sends this token to your backend.
3. Your backend executes the OBO flow to exchange that token for a new token. This new token is issued to your service for the resources you actually want to access (e.g. Calendar.Read in your example). The output of this OBO flow is both that access token as well as a [refresh token](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/making-authenticated-requests/refreshing-an-access-token/). If the access token expires, your backend can use the refresh token to acquire another one.
4. Your backend uses that token to access the desired resource.

*Eventually* the refresh token will also expire. In this case, your backend will need a new token from your client (repeating the above steps). However, this should be infrequent.

When using this flow, the users of your Teams app should normally not see any authentication/login UI (there may be *some* one-time or infrequent UI interrupts due to an initial consent prompt or other prompts (e.g. multi-factor auth) depending on the configuration of the tenant). No client secret or other sensitive information should need to be stored on the client. Finally, while all tokens will eventually expire, leveraging the refresh token received as part of the OBO flow will minimize the need to constantly be retrieving and sending tokens from the client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this flow perfectly works fine in browser as well as mobile clients. But, when we execute the OBO flow with the id token received from Desktop client, we are getting only access token and no refresh token. Could you please help us to debug why this could be happening,

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are seeing: when your middle tier uses the access token received from Desktop Teams to execute the OBO flow, the JSON response it gets back from login.microsoftonline.com doesn't contain a "refresh_token" property?

Comment: Does your OBO request include offline_access in the scope? That's usually the trigger to get a refresh_token.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, you are correct. We are not receiving the "refresh_token" property from the response in the OBO flow at the middle tier(our backend) when using the ID token received from the Desktop Teams client. In the Browser Teams client, we can clearly observe the "/token" API sent by the browser Teams client, which includes "offline_access" in the scope within the payload. However, in the Teams Desktop client, we are unable to observe the "/token" call made by the Teams client to check the scopes it is sending in payload.

Comment: I notice that you said you're looking at the scopes in the call made by the Teams client. The request with the offline_access scope needs to be coming from your middle tier when making the OBO request. You can see an example OBO request with that scope here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#example
Does the request that your middle tier makes to AAD to exchange the token as part of the OBO flow consistently include the offline_access scope?

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. We are able to execute the OBO flow correctly.